Question about Vector Search: Cosine Search vs. HNSW
I have a question about vector search. When I look into vector search, I come across two concepts: Cosine Search and HNSW (Hierarchical Navigable Small World). Both seem to be used for searching similar vector data, but I'm not sure whether they are used simultaneously or for different purposes.
Could someone clarify the differences between Cosine Search and HNSW? Are they used together in some scenarios, or are they typically employed for distinct purposes? Any examples or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Can you clarify what you mean by "vector search"? I think I know, but it would be great if you provided more info about your specific context.

In my understanding, vector search returns data with similar vector values, accompanied by a similarity score. I would like to know how HNSW and Cosine similarity work to score data similarities.
